# React Planner component drag and resizing events in items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

`I am trying to implement the resizing with mouse events in React planner catalog Items. they have it in lines and holes but not in items. I need help in storing the values of width and height in elements.properties.

this is my component I am working on

```
type hereimport * as Three from 'three';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

let WIDTH = 10;
let DEPTH = 80;
let HEIGHT = 200;

const textureLoader = new Three.TextureLoader();
const woodMaterial=textureLoader.load(require('./wood.jpg'));
const bookTexture1=textureLoader.load(require('./bookTexture1.jpg' ));
const bookTexture2=textureLoader.load(require('./bookTexture2.jpg' ));
const bookTexture3=textureLoader.load(require('./bookTexture3.jpg' ));

const objectMaxLOD = makeObjectMaxLOD();
const objectMinLOD = makeObjectMinLOD();


function makeObjectMaxLOD() {

  let bookcase = new Three.Mesh();

  //Bookcase`your text`
  let backGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.03,2,0.8);
  let wood = new Three.MeshPhongMaterial({map:woodMaterial});
  let backside = new Three.Mesh(backGeometry,wood);
  backside.position.set(0,1,0);
  bookcase.add(backside);

  let sideGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,2,0.03);
  let side1 = new Three.Mesh(sideGeometry,wood);
  side1.position.set(0.15,1,0.4);
  bookcase.add(side1);

  let side2 = new Three.Mesh(sideGeometry,wood);
  side2.position.set(0.15,1,-0.4);
  bookcase.add(side2);

  let bottomGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,0.03,0.8);
  let bottomPanel = new Three.Mesh(bottomGeometry,wood);
  bottomPanel.position.set(0.15,2,0);
  bookcase.add(bottomPanel);

  let topGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,0.03,0.8);
  let topPanel = new Three.Mesh(topGeometry,wood);
  topPanel.position.set(0.15,0.015,0);
  bookcase.add(topPanel);

  //shelves
  for(let i=1;i<5;i++){
    let shelveGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,0.03,0.8);
    let shelve = new Three.Mesh(shelveGeometry,wood);
    shelve.position.set(0.15,0.015+i*0.4,0);
    bookcase.add(shelve);
  }

  function choiceTexture() {

    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))

  }

  //book
  let bookGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.24,0.32,0.76);

  let bookMaterial =
    [ new Three.MeshLambertMaterial({map:bookTexture1}),
      new Three.MeshLambertMaterial({map:bookTexture2}),
      new Three.MeshLambertMaterial({map:bookTexture3})];

  let book1 = new Three.Mesh(bookGeometry,bookMaterial[choiceTexture()]);
  book1.position.set(0.15,0.59,0);
  bookcase.add(book1);

  let book2 = new Three.Mesh(bookGeometry,bookMaterial[choiceTexture()]);
  book2.position.set(0.15,0.99,0);
  bookcase.add(book2);

  let book3 = new Three.Mesh(bookGeometry,bookMaterial[choiceTexture()]);
  book3.position.set(0.15,0.19,0);
  bookcase.add(book3);

  let book4 = new Three.Mesh(bookGeometry,bookMaterial[choiceTexture()]);
  book4.position.set(0.15,1.39,0);
  bookcase.add(book4);

  let book5 = new Three.Mesh(bookGeometry,bookMaterial[choiceTexture()]);
  book5.position.set(0.15,1.79,0);
  bookcase.add(book5);

  return bookcase
}

function  makeObjectMinLOD() {

  let bookcase = new Three.Mesh();

  let textureLoader = new Three.TextureLoader();

  let woodMaterial=textureLoader.load(require('./wood.jpg'));

  //Bookcase
  let backGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.03,2,0.8);
  let wood = new Three.MeshPhongMaterial({map:woodMaterial});
  let backside = new Three.Mesh(backGeometry,wood);
  backside.position.set(0,1,0);
  bookcase.add(backside);

  let sideGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,2,0.03);
  let side1 = new Three.Mesh(sideGeometry,wood);
  side1.position.set(0.15,1,0.4);
  bookcase.add(side1);

  let side2 = new Three.Mesh(sideGeometry,wood);
  side2.position.set(0.15,1,-0.4);
  bookcase.add(side2);

  let bottomGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,0.03,0.8);
  let bottomPanel = new Three.Mesh(bottomGeometry,wood);
  bottomPanel.position.set(0.15,2,0);
  bookcase.add(bottomPanel);

  let topGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,0.03,0.8);
  let topPanel = new Three.Mesh(topGeometry,wood);
  topPanel.position.set(0.15,0.015,0);
  bookcase.add(topPanel);

  //shelves
  for(let i=1;i<5;i++){
    let shelveGeometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.3,0.03,0.8);
    let shelve = new Three.Mesh(shelveGeometry,wood);
    shelve.position.set(0.15,0.015+i*0.4,0);
    bookcase.add(shelve);
  }

  return bookcase

}


export default {
  
  name: 'Almirah',
  prototype: 'items',

  info: {
    tag: ['furnishings', 'wood'],
    title: 'Almirah',
    description: 'Almirah',
    image: require('./bricks.jpg'),
  },
 properties: {
    depth: {
      label: 'width',
      type: 'length-measure',
      defaultValue: {
        length: DEPTH,
        unit: 'cm',
      },
    },
    height: {
      label: 'height',
      type: 'length-measure',
      defaultValue: {
        length: HEIGHT,
        unit: 'cm',
      },
    },
  },
  

  
  render2D: function (element, layer, scene) {
    const angle = element.rotation + 90;
    let textRotation = 0;
    // if (element && element.properties && element.properties.get) {
    //   DEPTH = element.properties.get('depth')?.get('length') || DEPTH;
    //   HEIGHT = element.properties.get('height')?.get('length') || HEIGHT;
    // }
  
    if (Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) < 0) {
      textRotation = 180;
    }
  
    // let x1 = element.properties.get('x1')?.get('length') || 0;
    // let x2 = element.properties.get('x2')?.get('length') || DEPTH;
    // let y1 = element.properties.get('y1')?.get('length') || 0;
    // let y2 = element.properties.get('y2')?.get('length') || HEIGHT;
  
    // let initialWidth = DEPTH;
    // let initialHeight = HEIGHT;

    // State variables for resizing
    // State variables for resizing
    var [width, setWidth] = React.useState(element.properties.get('depth')?.get('length'));
    var [height, setHeight] = React.useState(element.properties.get('height')?.get('length'));
    var [isResizing, setIsResizing] = React.useState(false);
    var [initialMouseX, setInitialMouseX] = React.useState(0);
    var [initialMouseY, setInitialMouseY] = React.useState(0);
  
    // Event handler for mouse down
    const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
      setIsResizing(true);
      setInitialMouseX(event.clientX);
      setInitialMouseY(event.clientY);
    };
  
    // Event handler for mouse move
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
      if (!isResizing) return;
  
      const deltaX = event.clientX - initialMouseX;
      const deltaY = event.clientY - initialMouseY;
  
      setWidth(width + deltaX);
      setHeight(height + deltaY);
  
      setInitialMouseX(event.clientX);
      setInitialMouseY(event.clientY);
    };
        
    const handleMouseUp = () => {
      setIsResizing(false);
      let currentWidth = element.properties.get('depth').get('length')
      currentWidth = width
      let newdepth =element.properties.get('depth').set('length', currentWidth);
      let currentHeight = element.properties.get('depth').get('length')
      currentHeight = height
      let newheight =element.properties.get('height').set('length', currentHeight);

    };
    
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   // This effect will run after each render
    //   // Update the element properties with the new width and height values
    //   element.properties.get('width').set('length', width);
    //   element.properties.get('height').set('length', height);
    // }, [width, height]);

    
  
    
    return (
      <g transform={`translate(${-DEPTH / 2},${-HEIGHT / 2})`} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
         <rect
          x='0'
          y='0'
          width={width}
          height={height}
          style={{
            stroke: element.selected ? '#0096fd' : '#000',
            strokeWidth: '2px',
            fill: 'none', // Clear the fill
          }}
        />
        <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width={width} height={height} onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
            <img
              src={require('./wood.jpg')}
              alt="Wood Texture"
              style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
            />
          </div>
        </foreignObject>
        {/* <text
          x='0'
          y='0'
          transform={translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2}) scale(1,-1) rotate(${textRotation})}
          style={{ textAnchor: 'middle', fontSize: '11px' }}
        >
          {element.type}
        </text> */}
      </g>
    );
  },
  
  render3D: function (element, layer, scene) {
    let newAltitude = element.properties.get('altitude').get('length');

    /**************** lod max ******************/

    let bookcaseMaxLOD=new Three.Object3D();
    bookcaseMaxLOD.add(objectMaxLOD.clone());

    let value = new Three.Box3().setFromObject(bookcaseMaxLOD);

    let deltaX = Math.abs(value.max.x - value.min.x);
    let deltaY = Math.abs(value.max.y - value.min.y);
    let deltaZ = Math.abs(value.max.z - value.min.z);

    bookcaseMaxLOD.rotation.y+=Math.PI/2;
    bookcaseMaxLOD.position.y+= newAltitude;
    bookcaseMaxLOD.position.z+= WIDTH/2;
    bookcaseMaxLOD.scale.set(WIDTH / deltaX, HEIGHT / deltaY, DEPTH / deltaZ);

    /**************** lod min ******************/

    let bookcaseMinLOD=new Three.Object3D();
    bookcaseMinLOD.add(objectMinLOD.clone());
    bookcaseMinLOD.rotation.y+=Math.PI/2;
    bookcaseMinLOD.position.y+= newAltitude;
    bookcaseMinLOD.position.z+= WIDTH/2;
    bookcaseMinLOD.scale.set(WIDTH / deltaX, HEIGHT / deltaY, DEPTH / deltaZ);

    /**** all level of detail ***/

    let lod = new Three.LOD();

    lod.addLevel(bookcaseMaxLOD, 200);
    lod.addLevel(bookcaseMinLOD, 900);
    lod.updateMatrix();
    lod.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

    if (element.selected) {
      let bbox = new Three.BoxHelper(lod, 0x99c3fb);
      bbox.material.linewidth = 5;
      bbox.renderOrder = 1000;
      bbox.material.depthTest = false;
      lod.add(bbox);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(lod);

}

};
```

I have updated width and height in render2D function but now I want over-ride it in properties outside the function and as it is inside function so not accessible outside it.
i need help in storing the updated value in properties which is exported above.

this is the git repo of react-planner https://github.com/Luccid-ai/react-planner
`